# Trying to display live data from Telnet connection

Tags: php, sockets, web-applications, telnet

I've searched for a couple days I haven't found a solution for my problem.

I need to have a script connect to a telnet server send data to log in then display the output in a web page as the server sends is until the user leaves the page.

My experience is basic programing in PHP and Perl, but I'm willing to try others.

My initial thought is to write daemon script that connects to the server then repeats the data to the web clients via it's own server. Then when a user loads the web page a client connects to the daemon script.

Then telnet server only allows 1 connection from a specific user at a time that's why I'm thinking of the "Repeater" Server.

I'd like to have the data scroll up as it comes in. The data rate varies from several lines a second to minutes between lines depending on what's going on.

Can any one point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

There are several web-ssh-clients, one is with python on the server side and ajax in the browser. Maybe you can take this as an example. See http://antony.lesuisse.org/software/ajaxterm/